# Jaro Similarity

Tags: similarity, jaro-winkler

For finding Jaro similarity I found the matching charecters as follows

```
matching charecters in string 1 :  AABABCAAAC   
matching charecters in string 2 :  ABAACBAAAC
```

what is the value of t(0.5*transpositions)?
(source: wikipedia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpositions in this context are all those characters that don't match the same position on strings

from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance)

```
m = 10
t = 4/2 = 2
|S1| = 10
|S2| = 10
d = 1/3 * (10/10 + 10/10 + (10-2)/10) = 0.933
```

these transposition are [A/B, B/A, B/C, C/B] so `t` is calculed with `|[A/B, B/A, B/C, C/B]| / 2`.

Comment: @Curious transposition on this context are all these characters that doesn't match the same position on strings.

Comment: 1.  { abc , bac } transpositions are [a/b, b/a] 2. { abc,cba} here are [a/c, c/a] and 3.  {abc,cab} are [a/c, b/a, c/b]